# reporting abuse of phishing site (email not monitored)

Tags: reporting, abuse, phishing

The following server is phishing our university site:

http://webmailadm-unipi-it-src-login-php.mywap.lt/main.php?z=1

Looking into WHOIS database I find a contact email (which coincides with registrar email). I send an email and the response was:

```
Hello,

This is a system mailbox which is not monitored, your
e-mail will not be read or replied.

If you wish to contact UAB "[omissis]", please
visit: http://[omissis]
```

I'm not able to read the language in the website. I wonder if I can complain to someone because the official email is not being read. I think that abuse reporting should be straightforward... cannot spend hours to report a phishing site.

I'm I correct? What whould I do?

Comment: i've reported the site on the chat of this UAB

Answer (score 0):

For the posible abuse please write by email abuse@iv.lt. This kind of situations is not solving by chat.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you will reach anyone at this foreign site that will listen to your plea to shut down their phishing activities.  After blocking the domain and associated IP numbers at your mail server, have your security team block the domain and the range of IP numbers at the firewall as well.

I work financial, and we do this all the time.  If it's really bad, and some hacker is working from some ISP in Ukraine, I'll block the entire class C.  It also might be a good time to look into Geo Filtering.